# Java Array Beginner Menu

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a menu where the user has an option to add numbers to the array and technically they can add how many values they want but one at a time. So when they pick to add a number to the array, they would enter one number, and then it would prompt the menu again. I'm having trouble with adding the number to the array & displaying the array. I'll add two numbers & display the array to look at it & I get 30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 because of my array max, I think. all I want is for it to add only the digits I enter to the array when I want to enter it & continue to do that from there.

how exactly would I fix that though? I want the user to have complete control to how big the array will be, etc.

```
import java.util.*;

public class arrayMenu
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb;
      int option;
      kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      option = menu(kb);
      int[] myArray = new int[99];

      while (option != 6)
      {
         switch (option)
         {
            case 1:
               myArray = newNum(kb, myArray);
               break;
            case 2:
               display(myArray);
               break;
            case 3:

               break;
            case 4:

               break;
            case 5:

               break;
         }
         option = menu(kb);
      }
      if (option == 6)
      {
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Thank you. Have a nice day.");
      }
   }
   public static int menu(Scanner kb)
   {
      int myOption = 0;
      while (myOption != 1 && myOption != 2 && myOption != 3 && myOption != 4 && myOption != 5 && myOption != 6)
      {
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Please select from the following menu choices.");
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("1. Add a number to the array \n2. Display the mean \n3. Display the median \n4. Print the array to the screen \n5. Print the array in reverse order \n6. Quit");
         System.out.println();
         System.out.print("Choice --> ");
         myOption = kb.nextInt();
         kb.nextLine();
         if (!(myOption == 1 || myOption == 2 || myOption == 3 || myOption == 4 || myOption == 5 || myOption == 6))
            System.out.println("I am sorry that is an invalid menu choice.\nPlease try again"); 
      }
      return myOption;
   }
   public static int intNum(Scanner kb)
   {
      int num = -1;
      while (!(num >= 0))
      {
         System.out.print("Please enter a non-negative integer -->");
         num = kb.nextInt();

         if (num < 0)
            System.out.print("I am sorry that is not a non-negative integer.  \n");
      }
      return num;
   }
   public static int[] newNum(Scanner kb, int[] array) 
   {  
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
      { 
         System.out.print("Please enter a number:"); 
         array[i] = kb.nextInt(); 
      } 
      return array;
   }
   public static void display(int[] array)
   {
      for (int myValue : array)
      {
         System.out.print(myValue);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Java is not javascript. You sould remove the javascript tag from this question.

Comment: how exactly would I fix that though? I want the user to have complete control to how big the array will be, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well the newNum method looks very questionable. The loop is only going to around once since the loop counter test checks < 1.  i will always be 0 and you will always be adding the new number to the [0] place in the array.  You have no 'current index' variable to keep track of where your current place in the array is.  The array is going to be 1 int and the rest of the values will be 0 - which looks like what you included in the posting.

Comment: How exactly would I fix that though? I want the user to have complete control to how big the array will be, etc.

Comment: Why not use a List of Integers - you can just keep adding the numbers to the list and iterate thru the list once you need to perform some calculation on it.  Currently you are stuck at a fixed size of 99.

Comment: Its for an array assignment.

Comment: Well you could keep the numbers in the list and then there methods to create arrays from Lists - see the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray(T[]) where you can create the array from the list.  Otherwise, you could ask the user ahead of time for the max number of numbers to enter.  Then you can do int[] numbers = new int[max] to create that size array.   Enjoy your assigment!